# Unable to enable checkboxes in IE when using ASP.NET CheckBox controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, servercontrols

I have an HTML form with two disabled checkboxes and and image with an `onclick` event that needs to show a popup and enable the checkboxes:

```html
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
<input id="chk2" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
<img src="..." onclick="window.open('...'); document.getElementById('chk1').disabled=false;document.getElementById('chk2').disabled=false" />
```

except it doesn't work. The popup window opens, but the checkboxes never enable.

Instead of `disabled=false` I've tried `removeAttribute("disabled")` with no luck. I also placed the `window.open` as the last statement in the `onclick` with no change.

jQuery is not in this project (yet) so I can't use it. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

When I posted this, I failed to disclose the `input` tags are being rendered by ASP.NET. Through testing we've discovered there's a difference between using `<asp:CheckBox />` and `<input type="checkbox" runat="server" />` that affects how the `disabled` property behaves in IE and FF.

I've been under the impression that the final output would be the same, but apparently not, though I haven't been able to spot the difference. The rendered code as represented above works in FF but not IE when using an CheckBox object, but works in both when using an HtmlInputCheckBox object.

(I should also point out that the `getElementById` calls are actually using the ASP.NET ClientID property for the respective elements.)

My question now, then, is why is this the case? Why does the enable/disable functionality work in both IE and FF when using a HtmlInputCheckBox object but not for a CheckBox object?

Comment: It works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/rGMa9/

Comment: @Michael - What browser are you using? I was able to pretty much copy/paste your code into IE with no problems....

Comment: Your code works for me in Google Chrome.

Comment: IE8. Fortunately(?) this is for an intranet app where we can dictate the browser.

Comment: I just wanted to write what others have implied in their solutions below.  If you use a `<asp:CheckBox />`  and disable it on the server, the `<span>` that wraps it is also marked as disabled.  IE has trouble with this while FF & Chrome ignore it.  The only thing you need to do is `checkbox.parentNode.removeAttribute('disabled');`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this,

```
inputElement.removeAttribute( 'disabled' );
inputElement.closest('span').removeAttribute( 'disabled' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution. It works for me !

```
var checkBox = document.getElementById('" + chkBox.ClientID + "');
checkBox.removeAttribute('disabled');
checkBox.parentNode.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your network, second here is a link, a nice function to use for you

[Checkbox Disable/Enable JS Function](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2008/08/10/javascript-disableenable-checkbox/)

Answer (score 0):

To enable a checkbox, I generally apply both of the following:

```
inputElement.disabled = false;
inputElement.removeAttribute( 'disabled' );
```

Some browsers like the DOM node property, others want the attr adjusted.

I apologize if this is what you said you were doing which was not working--I wasn't quite clear on what you were saying.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
document.getElementById('chk1').getAttribute("disabled") = false;
```

Answer (score -2):

In fact, you do the oppisite to enable your checkbox. Try these...

```
document.formname.chkname.disabled='';
```

Comment: Think you have to enable irony setting first.